# Draw my array at a position defined with Vector2

Tags: xna, c#, vector

I'm developing a space invaders game in C# using XNA Game Studio. So I got some of the invader logic complete: An array holds the invaders and draws them on the screen, animated and moving.But I can't get the array to draw itself on a coordinate I spcify. I drew it with a `Vector2` and whatever values I put to it the drawn position never changes. Here is my invader class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Storage;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Net;

namespace SpaceInvaders
{
    class botInvaders
    {

        public botInvaders()
        {

        }

        public static Texture2D botInvaderTex;
        public static Rectangle botInvaderHitBox;
        public static Vector2 botInvaderPos = new Vector2(0, 24), botInvaderOrigin;

        int botInvaderCurrentFrame = 1, botInvaderFrameWidth = 52, botInvaderFrameHeight = 88;

        float spriteTimer = 0f, spriteInterval = 100;

        public static Rectangle[,] botInvadersRect;
        int invaderRows = 5, invaderCollumns = 10;
        String botInvadersDirection = "RIGHT";
        public static Color invadersColor = Color.White;

        public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
        {
            botInvaderTex = Content.Load<Texture2D>(".\\gameGraphics\\gameSprites\\botInvaders\\normalInvaders\\invaderShip1"); // invaderShip1
            botInvadersRect = new Rectangle[invaderRows, invaderCollumns];
            for (int r = 0; r < invaderRows; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < invaderCollumns; c++)
                {
                    botInvadersRect[r, c].Width = botInvaderFrameWidth;
                    botInvadersRect[r, c].Height = botInvaderTex.Height;
                    botInvadersRect[r, c].X = 70 * c;
                    botInvadersRect[r, c].Y = 70 * r;
                }
            }
        }

        public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            botInvaderHitBox = new Rectangle(botInvaderCurrentFrame * botInvaderFrameWidth, 0, botInvaderFrameWidth, botInvaderFrameHeight);
            botInvaderOrigin = new Vector2(botInvaderHitBox.X / 2, botInvaderHitBox.Y / 2);

            spriteTimer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;

            if (spriteTimer > spriteInterval)
            {
                botInvaderCurrentFrame++;
                spriteTimer = 0f;
            }

            if (botInvaderCurrentFrame == 2)
            {
                botInvaderCurrentFrame = 0;
            }

            botInvaderHitBox = new Rectangle(botInvaderCurrentFrame * botInvaderFrameWidth, 0, botInvaderFrameWidth, botInvaderFrameHeight);
            botInvaderOrigin = new Vector2(botInvaderHitBox.Width / 2, botInvaderHitBox.Height / 2);

            int m_RightSide = 800;
            int m_LeftSide = 0;

            for (int r = 0; r < invaderRows; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < invaderCollumns; c++)
                {
                    if (botInvadersDirection.Equals("RIGHT"))
                    {
                        botInvadersRect[r, c].X = botInvadersRect[r, c].X + 1;
                    }

                    if (botInvadersDirection.Equals("LEFT"))
                    {
                        botInvadersRect[r, c].X = botInvadersRect[r, c].X - 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            String botInvadersChangeDirection = "N";

            for (int r = 0; r < invaderRows; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < invaderCollumns; c++)
                {
                    if (botInvadersRect[r, c].X + botInvadersRect[r, c].Width > m_RightSide)
                    {
                        botInvadersDirection = "LEFT";
                        botInvadersChangeDirection = "Y";
                    }

                    if (botInvadersRect[r, c].X < m_LeftSide)
                    {
                        botInvadersDirection = "RIGHT";
                        botInvadersChangeDirection = "Y";
                    }
                }

                if (botInvadersChangeDirection.Equals("Y"))
                {
                    for (int c = 0; c < invaderCollumns; c++)
                    {
                        botInvadersRect[r, c].Y = botInvadersRect[r, c].Y + 3;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void Draw(Texture2D texture, Vector2 position, Rectangle[,] destinationRect, Nullable<Rectangle> sourceRect, Color color, float rotation, Vector2 origin, SpriteEffects effects, float scale, SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            for (int r = 0; r < invaderRows; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < invaderCollumns; c++)
                {
                    // spriteBatch.Draw(botInvaderTex, botInvaderPos, botInvadersRect[r, c], botInvaderHitBox, Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
                    spriteBatch.Draw(botInvaderTex, botInvadersRect[r, c], botInvaderHitBox, Color.White);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I initialized the class and drew it like this in Game1:

```
botInvader.Draw(botInvaders.botInvaderTex, botInvaders.botInvaderPos, botInvaders.botInvadersRect, botInvaders.botInvaderHitBox, Color.White, 0f, botInvaders.botInvaderOrigin, SpriteEffects.None, 1.0f, spriteBatch);
```

What should I change so that the array draws at `0, 24`, since it doesn't...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should have been:
`botInvadersRect[r, c].Y = (70 * r) + 24;`